# How to schedule jobs in Kubeflow?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, amazon-eks, kubeflow

I'm setting up a Kubeflow cluster on AWS EKS, is there a native way in Kubeflow that allows us to automatically schedule jobs i.e. (Run the workflow every X hours, get data every X hours, etc.)

I have tried to look for other things like Airflow, but i'm not really sure if it will integrate well with the Kubeflow environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be what a [recurring run](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/pipelines/overview/concepts/run/) is for.

That would be using a [run trigger](https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/pipelines/overview/concepts/run-trigger/), which does have a cron field, for specifying cron semantics for scheduling runs.